# Can not set CustomDomainName Error: "An operation is currently performing on this storage account that requires exclusive access"

Tags: powershell, azure, storage

I tried since 24 hours to set an new CustomDomainName of one of my storages. At first I tried in portal.azure.com, but this returns an internal error. After refreshing the page, was the unreachable, the word StorageAccountBladeWithQuickLinks only was visible.

My next try was to use Powershell. I executed the command: Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-NorthEurope" -AccountName "[storagename]" -CustomDomainName "[my domain]"

The response is:

> Set-AzureRmStorageAccount : An operation is currently performing on
>   this storage account that requires exclusive access. In Zeile:1
>   Zeichen:1
>   + Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "Default-Web-NorthEurope ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Set-AzureRmStorageAccount], CloudException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Management.Storage.SetAzureStorageAccountCommand

A CNAME for my domain is already available.

What can I do? Can the Azure data center observation team fix the problem?

Kind regards
Tino

Answer (score 0):

I didn't reproduce your error. But I can set a custom domain for my Storage. The steps are below:

1. **Add a CNAME record in your DNS provider**:Go to your Domain Provider to add a CNAME record. Example domain: `example.com`
   . You can just add CNAME `storage.example.com` to your storage account domain name `yourstorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net`.
2. Verified the domain name using Portal or powershell:

**For portal:** Go to Azure portal > Your storage Account > Custom domain > input the domain you added before > Save
[image]

**For Powershell**:Use `Set-AzureRmStorageAccount`

```
Set-AzureRmStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName yourrgname -Name yourstorageaccountname -CustomDomainName storage.example.com
```

I did a test in my lab and these two ways all work for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.

But, it isn't a general issue. I did the same like your description without success.
Your howto works, of course if the storage is not locked exclusive.

Comment: Hi,@Tino, Can you give me more details of your Storage account configuration?

Comment: It's a Hot locally-redundant Blobstorage hosted in North Europe (Dublin). On storage are not so many data, maybe 1 or 2GB images, videos and pdf files.

Comment: Hi,@Tino . Are you a owner of this storage ?